# Dropdown contents hidden behind content

Tags: css

I know this question has been asked across the net plenty of times already, but despite that, I still can't seem to figure out a feasible solution! :( I'm sure it's a simple fix...

As the title implies, I'm struggling to get some dropdown boxes to show its contents above everything else. I've tried z-index, which perhaps seems like the obvious solution... but perhaps I'm putting the code in the wrong place?

- Here's a video of the issue: [Link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNfHv.jpg)
- Here's a link to the issue: [Link 2](https://courses.darrylsyms.com/members/)

Your input and time is much appreciated! :)

As a bonus, if you can also figure out how to inline the left and right elements like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxuwu.jpg), good karma will be sent your way <3

Thanks,
- D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selector

```
#buddypress div.item-list-tabs ul li
```

is set to

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Remove that rule or change it to `visible` to show the drop-down menu.